# What is more optimal in Oracle 11G? Drop Recreate Indexes or just dbms_stats.gather

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is more optimal in Oracle 11G? Drop Recreate Indexes or just dbms_stats.gather.

Please advice.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Optimal for what? They do different things...

Comment: why rebuilding indexes?  If doing this on schedule, maybe consider this first: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6601312252730

Comment: Alex - There is a data intensive sql script that runs periodically weekly. We would like to speed up this script.

Comment: @Ram - Dropping and recreating indexes won't do that (and might make things worse, see tbone's link); unless you're talking about dropping, loading and then recreating. Gathering statistics will only help if the problem is that the existing statistics are stale or inaccurate and the explain plan(s) indicate it's not working as expected. You need to explain what you're doing and what problem you're seeing.

Comment: I would look at your code and carefully profile with ALTER SESSION ... and tkprof on a trace file. Or explain plan, at least, for all the sql in your massive script. First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 2 of the suggestions helped  me to get a better understanding of what needs to be done.

why rebuilding indexes? If doing this on schedule, maybe consider this first:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6601312252730
- tbone

Dropping and recreating indexes won't do that (and might make things worse, see tbone's link); unless you're talking about dropping, loading and then recreating. Gathering statistics will only help if the problem is that the existing statistics are stale or inaccurate and the explain plan(s) indicate it's not working as expected. You need to explain what you're doing and what problem you're seeing - Alex Poole